# local pypi server to serve windows, mac and linux users

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, portability, distutils

I have setup a local pypi server to allow local users to install python packages developed locally using `pip`.

I think that python packages are platform independent so one server will be serving all major platforms like windows, mac and linux. i.e. all users will be able to do `pip install package-name` to install package on their respective OS.

However, one of the hosted package contains opencv-python compiled using C++ as library.

I dont know what to do now?

Should I setup three separate Pypi servers for each platform because C++ is platfrom dependant or can I do it with one pypi server?

Should I keep separate packages like package-mac, package-win, package-lin?

Answer (score 1):

A project can upload a lot of binary wheels and binary eggs along with pure source distribution for a single release.

Example: https://pypi.org/project/Cheetah3/3.1.0/#files. This is release 3.1.0 of [CheetahTemplate](http://cheetahtemplate.org/) (full disclosure: I'm the current maintainer).

See the chapter [Packaging binary extensions](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-binary-extensions/) in [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/).

Comment: Thank you for reply, I was expecting any. I will read the references and come back to you.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. What I found is that PyPI is smart enough to send the right platform package to the customer. OR developer can host source code which is a bit slow but that is compiled on host after downloaded by the customer. However I am still struggling. How about if I have to store [this package](https://github.com/PlusToolkit/ndicapi) on my pypicloud server locally. Any idea how to tackle it.

Comment: *PyPI is smart enough to send the right platform package* Sorry, but that's wrong. PyPI doesn't send packages — it's `pip` that downloads them, so it's `pip` that is smart enough to get the right platform package.

Comment: As for your package — it should be packaged the smae way as any other C++-based package. For CMake-based packages see [setuptools+cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/setuptools+cmake).